# Копирование файлов с авторизацией

Tags: powershell, bat

Есть скрипт, который будет перемещать файлы с одного пк на другой, они в разных сетках. Я рассшариваю папку и подключаюсь к ней используя логин и пароль станции. Если я запускаю скрипт на powershell, то файлы перекидываются, но если запускаю его через scheduler, то копирования не происходит. Предполагаю не происходит авторизации логина и пароля.
Делал аналогичный батник, но тоже не знаю, как дополнить авторизацией его. Просьба подсказать

Get-ChildItem -Path "\172.18.3.20\d$\backup\1" -Recurse |
Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime.date -eq (date).date} |
Copy-Item -destination "\172.18.3.21\d$\Backup\1"

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы включить авторизацию в скрипте, вы можете использовать cmdkey. Ниже приведен пример:

```
cmdkey /add:172.18.3.20 /user:<Username> /pass:<Password>
Get-ChildItem -Path "\172.18.3.20\d$\backup\1" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime.date -eq (date).date} | Copy-Item -destination "\172.18.3.21\d$\Backup\1"
cmdkey /delete:172.18.3.20
```

В этом примере, вместо  и  вы должны указать свои учетные данные для подключения к сетевому ресурсу.

Comment: При отработке пишет CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
Сам по себе скрипт запускается и работает, но через scheduler не отрабатывает. Если запустить копирование между папок на одном пк, то шедулер работает

Comment: Возможным решением может быть сохранение учетных данных в задаче Scheduler, используя опцию "Запускать от имени" в параметрах задачи.
@Archi

Comment: Я создал две одинаковые учетки, с одинаковыми паролями. https://ibb.co/XZpcbxz